# azure policy 'modify' effect vs remediation

Tags: azure, azure-policy

For an azure policy I can make the changes I desire with "**modify/deployIfNotExists**" if needed. So why do I need a remediation task?

```
 "then": {
                "effect": "modify",
                "details": {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks",
                    "existenceCondition": {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks/level",
                        "equals": "CanNotDelete"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Azure Policy's main function is to show compliance and non-compliance of Azure resources. It will answer the question "WHAT is compliant?". This is true for all policy effect types.

Remediations go a step further from defining "WHAT" by also defining "HOW" (HOW to make a non-compliant, compliant) THIS IS WHY YOU NEED A REMEDIATION TASK.

A remediation task is simply an Azure ARM Resource that represents a minimally compliant resource. Whether you are modifying an existing resource or deploying a new sub-resource is why you would choose Modify or DeployIfNotExists. Both types however would require a remediation task because a deployment must be triggered upon the non-compliant evaluation of a remediatable effect (like modify or deployIfNotExists). The ARM resource definition must exist as part of the policy so that Azure Policy knows HOW to remediate the non-compliance.

Comment: How does this act on newly created resource? Do we need to manually keep using remediation?

Comment: In summary, new resources that are created after the policy is assigned will auto-remediate. Resources that existed before the policy was assigned require manually triggering of the remediation task. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#deployifnotexists see the docs for more accurate details.

Comment: In addition existing resources that are modified will also trigger an auto-remediation.